# I am trying to save response in an array into an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, frontend

```
let response = [
    {
      id: 1,
      user_name: 'abc',
      phone_number: 1234567890
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      user_name: 'def',
      phone_number: 9823437483
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      user_name: 'ghi',
      phone_number: 9834763467
    }];
```

I am trying to save response in an object like `{abc:{ id: 1, user_name: 'abc', phone_number: 1234567890}, def: {id: 2, user_name: 'def', phone_number: 9823437483}}`

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: Question is I wants to create an object in which key is response.user_name and value is indexs of an array(response)

Answer (score 4):

You can the [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method on the `response` array to create an **object** where each key is the `user_name` and the corresponding value is the entire object for that user.

**Code:**

```js
let response = [
    {
      id: 1,
      user_name: 'abc',
      phone_number: 1234567890
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      user_name: 'def',
      phone_number: 9823437483
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      user_name: 'ghi',
      phone_number: 9834763467
    }];

let obj = response.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr.user_name] = curr;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Reduce method is very useful for data transformation. Read about [Reduce method here !](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
let response = [
  {
    id: 1,
    user_name: "abc",
    phone_number: 1234567890,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    user_name: "def",
    phone_number: 9823437483,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    user_name: "ghi",
    phone_number: 9834763467,
  },
];

const result = response.reduce((acc, userDetail) => {
  acc[userDetail.user_name] = {
    ...userDetail,
  };
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can covert it to an object with a simple for loop:

```
let resObj = {}
for (let item of response) {
   resObj[item.user_name] = item
}
```

Result:

```
{
    "abc": {
        "id": 1,
        "user_name": "abc",
        "phone_number": 1234567890
    },
    "def": {
        "id": 2,
        "user_name": "def",
        "phone_number": 9823437483
    },
    "ghi": {
        "id": 3,
        "user_name": "ghi",
        "phone_number": 9834763467
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you wanted to transform your data into object, you can use `reduce` to achieve it. In the result object, each object from the original array is assigned to the key which is value of original object's `user_name` :

```js
let response = [
  {
    id: 1,
    user_name: 'abc',
    phone_number: 1234567890
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    user_name: 'def',
    phone_number: 9823437483
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    user_name: 'ghi',
    phone_number: 9834763467
  }
];

let result = response.reduce((acc, curr) => (acc[curr.user_name] = curr, acc), {});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce and do the following:

```js
const object = {};
return array.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    return {
      ...prev,
      [curr[curr.user_name]]: curr,
    };
}, object);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use a [forEach loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
let response = [{
    id: 1,
    user_name: 'abc',
    phone_number: 1234567890
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    user_name: 'def',
    phone_number: 9823437483
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    user_name: 'ghi',
    phone_number: 9834763467
  }
];

const response_obj = {}
response.forEach(item => {
  response_obj[item.user_name] = {
    id: item.id,
    user_name: item.user_name,
    phone_number: item.phone_number
  }
})
```

or you could [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the response. something like this

```js
let response = [{
     id: 1,
     user_name: 'abc',
     phone_number: 1234567890
   },
   {
     id: 2,
     user_name: 'def',
     phone_number: 9823437483
   },
   {
     id: 3,
     user_name: 'ghi',
     phone_number: 9834763467
   }
 ];

 function getItemByUserName(userName) {
   return response.filter(item => 
     item.user_name == userName
   )[0]
 }

 console.log(getItemByUserName("def"))
```

note!: there is no logic if the user_name is unique or not

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```js
let response = [
    {
      id: 1,
      user_name: 'abc',
      phone_number: 1234567890
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      user_name: 'def',
      phone_number: 9823437483
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      user_name: 'ghi',
      phone_number: 9834763467
    }];

const data ={};
response.forEach(item=>{
    data[item.user_name] = {...item};
})

console.log(data);
```